# How do I get first json file in a website json api?

Tags: node.js, json, api, discord.js

**I need to know how to get the first JSON file in a website API, the website is in JSON format if you are wondering.**

*For example; when there are multiple of JSON files in 1 API, how do I get the first one?*
Screenshot: https://i.gyazo.com/075aba4bae2e4d3d95af2926f4df436f.png

Code:

```
if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + "check")){
  snekfetch.get(api).then(r => {
    var body = r.body;
    if(!body){ return }
    var creator = body.Creator
    var desc = body.Description
    var name = body.Name
    var sales = body.Sales
    var price = body.Price
    var itemLink = body.AbsoluteUrl
    var thumbnail = body.ThumbnailUrl

    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(name)
    .setDescription(desc)
    .addField("Price:", price)
    .addField("Sales:", sales)
    .setImage(thumbnail)
    .setFooter("By "+creator)
    message.channel.send(embed);
  })
}
```

Comment: I mean like getting first body!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all one json in form of array, I think what you want to achieve is to get first item from that array

```
snekfetch
  .get(api)
  .then(r => {
    const firstItem = r.body[0]
    ...
  })
```